# Which package contains ddate?

Tags: debian

I am using Debian8 (Jessie) and I have discovered a concerning lack of the ddate command. I have very important programs that rely on getting charming date and cometary data from the ddate program.

I have util-linux installed, but ddate isn't working. Perhaps some sort of evil has absconded with it.

System users have already begun to complain, they cannot access the command `ddate   %.`

Comment: Since ddate is not a standard tool we can hardly speak of a bug. (But since `ddate` is available on the Net anyway you can find it there, get it, and let the sysadmins install it.)

Comment: We can most certainly speak of a bug.  Two, in fact: [650321](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=650321) and [764383](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=764383).  Neither had severity critical.

Comment: I remember when ddate was part of coreutils. This is a dank dark road we are headed down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt install ddate` should allow your [essential research](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/196623/1) to proceed.

In general, you can find packages with commands like `apt search ddate`, or various graphical package management frontents. You can also use the web site http://packages.debian.org/ to search (remembering that Jessie is currently "testing").

Comment: Praise Eris! That did it!.  You sir are officially a pope!